# connectionstring failure

Tags: asp.net

can somebody help me with the following problem?

I've developed an ASP.net application with login page on my laptop, i've a local SQL database on my laptop with several tables. It works like this; in visual studio i debug my APP, my login page opens and i log in with my credentials, it works!
But, i moved the application to a dedicated server, i installed als a sql server on that machine with OS W2003 server, i imported the tables en copied my ASP files, IIS is also installed! When i try to browse to my website, i get the folowing error;(in the connectionstrin i changed the ip adres!)

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'connectionString'

Source Error:

```
<configuration>
<connectionString>
  <add name="TelefoonConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=172.30.111.174;Initial Catalog=Telefoon;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

> Source File: C:\Telefoon\Telefoon\web.config    Line: 9

Comment: Know it's a bit late for an answer, but does the new database require an login, if so, you need to add the username and password into the connectionstring. If not, it won't be able to connect to the new database.

Answer (score 1):

It's connectionStrings afaik...

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TelefoonConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=172.30.111.174;Initial Catalog=Telefoon;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I know, i already changed that, but still doesn't work, still same failure.

Answer (score 1):

Its **connectionStrings** instead of **connectionString**

Use the following corrected entry

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TelefoonConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=172.30.111.174;Initial Catalog=Telefoon;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I know, i already changed that, but still doesn't work, still same failure.